# AVL trees in scheme

Tags: data-structures, tree, functional-programming, scheme, avl-tree

I'm trying to implement an AVL tree in Scheme. My approach to this task was to initially make an initial tree representation and progressively implement AVL properties after completing so. I've tried to implement it as such and it won't work because I keep getting an undefined identifier error for both my rotation and deletion functions. Could anyone help me decipher this or aid in my implementation of an AVL tree? My code is as follows:

```
(define (make-tree value left right)
  (list value left right))

(define (key tree)
  (car tree))

(define (left-tree tree)
  (cadr tree))

(define (right-tree tree)
  (caddr tree))

(define (make-leaf key) (list key '() '()))

(define (empty-tree) '())

(define (isEmpty? tree)
  (null? tree))

(define (size tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) 0)
    (else (+ 1 (size (left-tree tree))
             (size (right-tree tree))))))

(define (height tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) 0)
       (else (+ 1 (max (height (right-tree tree))
                       (height (left-tree tree)))))))


(define (isValid? val left-tree right-tree)
               (and (>= val left-tree)
                    (< val right-tree)))

(define (isLeaf? tree)
  (and (isEmpty? (left-tree tree))
       (isEmpty? (right-tree tree))))

(define (delete tree val)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) (empty-tree))
        ((= val (key tree)) (remove-root tree))
        ((< val (key tree))
         (make-tree (key tree) (delete (left tree) val) (right tree)))
        ((> val (val tree)) (make-tree (key tree)
                                   (right tree)
                                   (delete (right tree) val)))))



(define (delete-root tree)
    (cond ((isLeaf? tree) (empty-tree))
      ; If one child exists then return that child and its descendants
      ((isEmpty? (left tree)) (right tree))
      ((isEmpty? (right tree)) (left tree))
      ;Two children exists
      (else (let* ((new-value (key (leftmost-child (right tree))))
                   (new-right-tree (delete (right tree) new-value)))
              (make-tree new-value (left-tree tree) new-right-tree)))))


;Inserts a value into a tree
;Does not obey AVL properties
(define (insert value tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) (list value () ()))
        ((= value (key tree)) tree) ;Value is in tree
        ((< value (key tree))
         (list (key tree) (insert value (left-tree tree)) (right-tree tree)))
        (else (list (key tree) (left-tree tree) (insert value (right-tree tree))))))


;Returns the leftmost-child of an input tree
(define (leftmost-child tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) empty-tree)
        ((isEmpty? (left-tree tree)) tree)
        (else (leftmost-child (left-tree tree)))))

;Makes a tree from an input list
(define (list-to-tree list-in)
  (define (list-to-tree-helper list-in tree)
    (cond ((null? list-in) tree)
          (else (list-to-tree-helper (cdr list-in)
                                 (insert (car list-in) tree)))))
  (list-to-tree-helper list-in ()))

 ;Checks if the heights of the left and right subtrees are equal
 (define (isBalanced? tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) #t)
        (else (and (= (height (left-tree tree))
                      (height (right-tree tree)))
                   (= (isBalanced? (left-tree tree))
                      (isBalanced? (right-tree tree)))))))

;left rotation
(define (rotate-left tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) tree)
        (else (make-tree (key tree)
                         (left (left tree))
                         (make-tree (key tree) (right (left tree) (right tree))))))

;right rotation
(define (rotate-right tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) tree)
        (else (make-tree (key (right tree))
                         (make-tree (key tree) (left tree) (left (right tree)))
                         (right (right tree))))))

;right-left
(define (rotate-right-left tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) tree)
        (else (make-tree (key (left (right tree)))
                         (make-tree (key tree) (left tree) (left (left (right tree))))
                         (make-tree (key (right tree)) (right (left (right tree))) (right (right tree)))))))
 ;left-right
 (define (rotate-left-right tree)
  (cond ((isEmpty? tree) tree)
        (else (make-tree (key (right (left tree)))
                         (make-tree (key (left tree)) (left (left tree)) (left (right (left tree))))
                         (make-tree (key tree) (right (right (left tree))) (right tree))))))

 ;Avl-tree factor 
(define (avl-factor tree)
  (- (height (left tree)) (height (right tree))))


;Balance tree according to avl tree properties:
;|h_l - h_r| = -2 < h < 2
(define (avl-balance tree)
  (let ((factor (avl-factor tree)))
    (cond ((= factor -2)
           ;left tree is bigger
           (cond ((> (factor (left tree)) 0) (rotate-left-right tree))
                 (else (rotate-left tree))))
          ((= factor 2)
           ;right tree is bigger
           (cond ((< (factor (right tree)) 0) (rotate-right-left tree))
                 (else (rotate-right tree))))
          (else tree))))


;(list-to-tree '(4 2 6 8 1 7))
;(define my-tree (make-tree 5 () () ))
(define my-tree (list-to-tree '(4 2 6 8 1 7)))
(isEmpty? my-tree)
(size my-tree)
(height my-tree)
(isLeaf? my-tree)

;Does not work
;(delete 6 my-tree)
;(delete 4 my-tree)
;(delete 7 my-tree)
;does not work
;(delete-root my-tree)
(leftmost-child my-tree)
(rotate-right my-tree)
```

Comment: from your code, `remove-root` doesn't seem to be defined. I guess it should be `delete-root`

Comment: One thing you could do to make it easier to work is to use some kind of test module and run tests against your code. It will be easier to locate errors as scheme usually don't have much debuggers. Something like that might be a day saver: http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/missbehave#examples

Comment: You might enjoy these [two](https://programmingpraxis.com/2011/11/25/avl-trees/) [entries](https://programmingpraxis.com/2011/11/29/avl-trees-extended/) at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/), or [this](https://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/#dictionaries) from my [Standard Prelude](https://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude).